# google line chart add new shapes

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I need to add a new shape to google line charts. Google charts allow the following shape types: circle, triangle, square, diamond, star and polygon, but i need to set "pi" shape in a series as well as two other shapes.

It is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Charts LineChart Custom Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661406/google-charts-linechart-custom-points)

Comment: ^ that question deals with styling the points already in place, not changing the shape of the point -- and there isn't an option for adding a custom shape -- you would have to modify the svg when the `'ready'` event fires on the chart...

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat Is there any way more simple? for example, charge a png instead of make a svg by coordinates?